# I installed django dynamic scraper to my app and when i pushed it my app broke

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-dynamic-scraper

I added django dynamic scraper to my app. it worked locally so I deployed it to my heroku server and It's giving me a server error of 500. I have no error messages in my heroku logs and it works fine locally. since I have no errors and it works locally I didn't know what top post and was wondering if someone may have had the same issue. This si crazy to me.

## EDIT

I've done some digging. I tried to

```
 heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
```

and got this

```
Running python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ heights... up, run.1515
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 65, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 306, in build_graph
    _reraise_missing_dependency(migration, parent, e)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 276, in _reraise_missing_dependency
    raise exc
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 302, in build_graph
    self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 126, in add_dependency
    parent
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration blog.0011_auto_20160816_1834 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('dynamic_scraper', '0018_auto_20160816_1834')
```

## EDIT

this is my 0011_auto_20160816_1834.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # Generated by Django 1.9.2 on 2016-08-16 22:34
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import migrations, models
    import django.db.models.deletion


    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

        dependencies = [
            ('dynamic_scraper', '0018_auto_20160816_1834'),
            ('blog', '0010_auto_20160627_1133'),
        ]

        operations = [
            migrations.CreateModel(
                name='NewsWebsite',
                fields=[
                    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                    ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                    ('scraper', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='dynamic_scraper.Scraper')),
                    ('scraper_runtime', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='dynamic_scraper.SchedulerRuntime')),
                ],
            ),
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='post',
                name='news_website',
                field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='blog.NewsWebsite'),
            ),
        ]
```

can I just delete

```
('dynamic_scraper', '0018_auto_20160816_1834'),
```

an run the migrations again? I don't want to completely crash my app. Novice programmer and not completely sure of the affects of doing that on my app.

## EDIT

when I run show migrations

```
(practice) apples-MBP:src ray$ ./manage.py showmigrations
    admin
     [X] 0001_initial
     [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
    auth
     [X] 0001_initial
     [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
     [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
     [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
     [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
     [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
     [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
    blog
     [X] 0001_initial
     [X] 0002_auto_20160404_2019
     [X] 0003_post_image_url
     [X] 0004_auto_20160406_2353
     [X] 0005_image
     [X] 0006_auto_20160603_2317
     [X] 0007_auto_20160603_2326
     [X] 0008_auto_20160625_1708
     [X] 0009_auto_20160627_1034
     [X] 0010_auto_20160627_1133
     [X] 0011_auto_20160816_1834
    contenttypes
     [X] 0001_initial
     [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
    dynamic_scraper
     [X] 0001_initial
     [X] 0002_scraper_render_javascript
     [X] 0003_auto_20150610_0906
     [X] 0004_scrapedobjattr_id_field
     [X] 0005_new_dict_params_for_scraper
     [X] 0006_request_type_and_body
     [X] 0007_dont_filter_attribute
     [X] 0008_new_request_page_types_construct
     [X] 0009_removed_legacy_request_page_type_scraper_fields
     [X] 0010_move_save_to_db_to_scraped_obj_attr
     [X] 0011_extracted_checker_attributes_to_own_checker_class
     [X] 0012_removed_legacy_checker_scraper_attributes
     [X] 0013_added_scraper_save_and_checker_delete_datetime_fields
     [X] 0014_added_scraper_save_and_checker_delete_alert_period_fields_for_scraper
     [X] 0015_added_datetime_fields_for_last_scraper_save_and_checker_delete_alert
     [X] 0016_optional_xpath_fields_text_type_for_x_path_reg_exp_processor_fields
     [X] 0017_added_order_to_scraped_obj_attr
     [X] 0018_auto_20160816_1834
    sessions
     [X] 0001_initial
    taggit
     [X] 0001_initial
     [X] 0002_auto_20150616_2121
```

## EDIT when I run it on my showmigrations on my production server

```
(practice) apples-MBP:src ray$ heroku run python manage.py showmigrations
Running python manage.py showmigrations on ⬢ cheights... up, run.7252
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/showmigrations.py", line 36, in handle
    return self.show_list(connection, options['app_labels'])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/showmigrations.py", line 44, in show_list
    loader = MigrationLoader(connection, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 306, in build_graph
    _reraise_missing_dependency(migration, parent, e)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 276, in _reraise_missing_dependency
    raise exc
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 302, in build_graph
    self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 126, in add_dependency
    parent
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration blog.0011_auto_20160816_1834 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('dynamic_scraper', '0018_auto_20160816_1834')
```

Comment: @loose It looks like the file ```dynamic_scraper /migrations/0018_auto_20160816_1834.py``` is not on your production sever. Can you check that

Comment: @luke_aus Check it out. the dependency '0018_auto_20160816_1834' which it says doesn't exist is from dynamic scraper

Comment: @loose well check on your production server that the file is actually there. i.e. run ```./manage.py showmigrations``` on your production server

Comment: @loose also add what is in this 0018_auto_20160816_1834 file on you macbook to the description

Comment: No @luke_aus I get the traceback about it not existing. I just posted the traceback after your last response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121115/discussion-between-luke-aus-and-losee).

Comment: @luke_aus I am using pyhton 3.5 the docs say 3.4+ so that may be the issue